# how to keep files on the external hard drive, when you wanna make it live drive?

Tags: system-installation

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and wanna install 18.04 from an external hard drive.Is it possible to keep my files on my external hard drive when I am making it live drive? if yes, how?
Thanks

Comment: not really sure it's possible, when you create a live drive, you must format this hard drive (so all data are erased with it)

Comment: But when I was using Win10 , I used Rufus.  It didn't ask to format the whole drive. it only asked to erase the files in the dir that I am gonna burn into

Comment: erase files probably means format the whole hard drive

Comment: You could possibly shrink your partition with the files and create a second partition in the free space and use that as "live drive". But I'm not at all sure if that will work.

Comment: It may be possible, but it is complicated and risky, to keep files on the external hard drive, when you want to make it a live drive. I would not recommend it, because you might lose those files because of some misunderstanding or mistake. It is much better to get (buy or borrow) a cheap USB pendrive (size 2 GB or bigger) and make it a USB boot drive with Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudodus I have been googling this since I posted and the result is I will buy  another USB pendrive.

Comment: Maybe [this link and links from it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Prerequisites) can help you select which USB pendrive to buy. Good luck :-)